# Third party Integration react/node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, third-party-cookies

I'm facing an issue from past 2 days,
Issue is that I'm trying to call 3rd party API in my react/node project,
That third part API is a blocking service of a specific company, which is blocking and unblocking files based on their generated hashes, but it's company policy that I have to login to their service to use that blocking list, now if I'm redirecting user to log into that service and get back to use it, I can't even after logging in, I get cors error, I've tried everything with the cors from everywhere but nothing worked out, and when I try to use that service in that specific organization portal, I can easily use it there.
How can I get that thing integrated in my application.

Comment: If you are using post requests, you probably should send `csrf` token

Comment: If they don't allow CORS then it's possible they may be specifically trying to *prevent* what you're doing.  Integrating a 3rd party service is basically either (1) contact them and integrate according to their specifications or (2) try to reverse-engineer or get around their specifications and hope for the best.  In either case I don't see how we can be much help without *any* technical information about the problem.